# Why can't CSS padding be partially inherited using shorthand?

Tags: css, inheritance

From time to time when browsing through stylesheets, I have seen rules such as the following:

```
padding: 10px inherit;
```

I didn't know if this was valid CSS so I made 3 JSFiddles. All 3 fiddles have a `<p>` child of a `<div>` parent (and were tested in Chrome 59.0). In the [first JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrf922ff/), the child inherits the parent padding (a single `inherit` keyword) and inspection of the elements show both `<p>` and `<div>` have 10px padding in both the x- and y-directions:

```
div {padding: 10px 10px}
p {padding: inherit}
```

In the [second JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrf922ff/1/), the child `<p>` has both x and y padding explicitly inherited (1 actual `<length>`, 1 `inherit` keyword):

```
div {padding: 10px 10px}
p {padding: 10px inherit}
```

Inspection of `<p>` shows the CSS has broken (i.e., no padding inherited);

In the [third JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrf922ff/2/) (for completeness), the child `<p>` also has both x and y padding explicitly inherited, but in this case there are 2 separate `inherit` keywords:

```
div {padding: 10px 10px}
p {padding: inherit inherit}
```

and this CSS also breaks for `<p>` (i.e., no padding inherited)

I am assuming this means that child elements cannot "partially" inherit parent property values using shorthand. *Is this correct, and if so, why can it not be partially inherited?* (i.e., do the W3C docs mention this somewhere?).

UPDATE - If you split the padding property explicitly (don't use shorthand), you CAN inherit (see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrf922ff/3/))

Considering that I have seen case #2 (second Fiddle) in several stylesheets, it looks like other developers also think partial inheritance is valid.

Comment: *do the W3C docs mention this somewhere?* - Yes they do. Right here: [padding](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html#padding-properties). The `value` of `padding` can either be `<padding-widht>{1,4}` or `inherit` and not `inherit{1,4}`.

Comment: OK so this is only about syntax since you can "partially inherit" by just splitting the shorthand into longhand

Comment: Yup. Which is not a big deal. As you can imagine that the possibilities of mixing shorthand and longhand, to inherit and overwriting rules should give you a lot of space to play. ;)

Answer (score 3):

The spec presesnts three options for a property `unset`,`all` and `inherit` https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#propdef-all It even says `initial | inherit | unset`.  It means these values in a literal sense.  Because it wouldn't make sense to define `backround:url('url.png') inherit;`.  This is a hard coded example of how the engine works internally.  It is sort of like defining partial importance like `padding:20px !important 10px;`.  No you have to do `padding:!important 10px;`

Comment: But you can actually inherit in the way I am suggesting just by not using shorthand: see https://jsfiddle.net/Lrf922ff/3/ . I will update my question

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob yes but you can't use shorthand on `!important` syntax either for a similar reason.

Comment: So in other words you cannot partially inherit using shorthand - why? Does a W3C doc state somewhere that inherit, unset, etc. only apply to entirety of parent property?

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob yes essentially `inherit`, `unset` and `all` work the same way https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit not using shorthand

Comment: OK - this line from the cascade doc does it for me: "Declaring a shorthand property to be !important is equivalent to declaring all of its sub-properties to be !important." - close enough

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know why this is the case, you can do the following trick:

```
div {padding: 10px 10px}
p {
  padding: inherit;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question of partial inheritance