# Unset CSS keyword not working when using shorthand

Tags: css, shorthand

I thought that setting a property such as:

```
padding-top: 25px;
```

was equivalent as doing the following (using shorthand):

```
padding: 25px unset  unset  unset;
```

However, this does not appear to be the case since the browser gives me a different results. Why is this? Just out of curiosity, how can achieve setting ***padding-top: 25px*** using the padding shorthand (just for fun).

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check for any overrides?

Comment: why complicating ... unset = 0

Comment: If all you want to do is set `padding-top`, don't use a shorthand. You can't set that without affecting the others.

Comment: @T555 - [Why can't CSS padding be partially inherited using shorthand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45307151/why-cant-css-padding-be-partially-inherited-using-shorthand) - this should help in gaining an understanding of CSS inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

> The unset CSS keyword resets a property to its inherited value if it
>   inherits from its parent, and to its initial value if not. In other
>   words, it behaves like the inherit keyword in the first case, and like
>   the initial keyword in the second case. It can be applied to any CSS
>   property, including the CSS shorthand all.

[The Unset CSS Key Word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset)

To get the shorthand notation for `padding-top: 25px` in CSS it would be:

```
  padding: 25px 0 0 0;
```

If you only wanted to set the top padding then the shorthand for

```
padding-top: 25px;
```

would be exactly that, `padding-top: 25px;`

There is no partial inheritance for padding shorthand. Shorthand is kinda an all or nothing kinda thing.

Comment: Most of this answer is copied from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset

Comment: This also isn't the shorthand for padding-top because it overwrites padding-bottom, padding-left, padding-right and places it at 0.

Comment: @mfluehr The entire first paragraph is copied from that site. Was in the middle of adding the link.

Comment: @thatguy Thanks, I see you've now attributed your source.

Comment: @MathiasRechtzigel that is true and also what I thought T555 was trying to accomplish. That being said, There is no partial inheritance using shorthand notation in CSS, So, if you are going to use shorthand then it's all or nothing.