# Override more property in a more specific rule

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've stumbled upon the following problem: I have `navbar-nav` class element which contains elements of `nav-link` class and I want to set padding for `nav-link` since text seems to not fit in the element's boundaries. And I'm using the Bootstrap 5 CSS framework.
Obviously, I tried writing this:

```css
.nav-link {
    border: 2px solid var(--my-palette-3);
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: inherit 2em;
}
```

But looking into styles tab in dev tools I found out that there is a rule defined in Bootstrap which is more specific than mine:

```css
.navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

So i tried to specify `!important` to the padding property, but it didn't work out.

I wrote this rule to see if this would override the Bootstrap's rule:

```css
.navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding: inherit 2em !important;
}
```

But, to my surprise, this rule doesn't override padding either.
Why does this happen? And what should I do to properly override more specific rule I can't control?

Comment: Alright, I figured out that `inherit` was the reason it didn't work. The other question then would be: is it possible to partially inherit a property?

Comment: No it's not... !

Comment: `padding: inherit 2em;` is invalid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't CSS padding be partially inherited using shorthand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45307151/why-cant-css-padding-be-partially-inherited-using-shorthand)